# How to install jQuery UI in Rails app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use jQuery UI in my rails app. I have installed the gem packages:

```
gem list |grep jquery
jquery-rails (4.0.4)
jquery-ui-rails (5.0.5)
```

add below code to `/app/assets/javascripts/application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui
```

but doesn't work, the error as below:

```
Showing /Users/liuxin/Public/my_blog/mongo_project/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:
couldn't find file 'jquery.ui' with type 'application/javascript'
```

Hope someone can help me , thanks in advance!

rails version: `Rails 4.2.3`

ruby version:  `ruby 2.2.2`

Comment: Have you restarted the server after installing a gem?

Comment: @BroiSatse yes, I restarted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ui
```

Comment: I have added `//= require jquery`

Comment: But did you added jquery_ui or jquery.ui ?

Comment: oh, it is my mistake, it is underscore not dot, thanks a lot!